# What does 容姿 mean at the end of the sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I know that 容姿 means (physical) appearance (of a person); one's face and figure.

But I cannot figure it in the following context:(at the end of the sentence)

> やはり新参者は珍しいのかやけに注目を集めている 。...と、俺はその原因に気がついた。「ねえねえ、いやに見られてるんですけど。これってアレよ、きっと私から滲み出る神オーラで、女神だってバレてるんじゃないかしら」このすっとぼけた事を言う女神の**容姿** 。黙っていれば美少女なこいつが目を惹いているのだろう。

It has been translated as

> We did seem to be getting a lot of attention, though. At first I
> thought maybe they didn't many newcomers here. Then it dawned on me.
> "Hey I don't like the way they're looking at me" Aqua said. "I know !
> It's the goddess aura I exude - They've figured out who I really am!"
> Everyone was checking out the goddess who stood beside me, spewing
> inanities. It made sense that she would attract attention. After all,
> she would be really beautiful, if she could keep her mouth shut.

My try for the part with 容姿

> "They figured out I am a goddess" (said) the beautiful goddess who
> suddendly was saying nonsense

I wonder if 容姿 does not add an ironic touch.

Comment: その質問に答えるには、『やけに**注目を集めている** 。...と、俺は**その原因**に気がついた。「ねえねえ、いやに見られてるんですけど。これってアレよ、きっと私から滲み出る神オーラで、女神だってバレてるんじゃないかしら」このすっとぼけた事を言う女神の**容姿** 。黙っていれば**美少女なこいつが目を惹いているのだ**ろう。』まで引用しないと無理ですよ。 ☝ To answer your question we need at least this much context.

Comment: Ok I will update it

Comment: Off-topic, but this いやに見られてる is not "I don't like the way". This type of いやに means something like "strangely often", "oddly often". https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%84%E3%82%84%E3%81%AB/

Comment: Oh thanks for the comment, I was not aware of this meaning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 容姿 is referring to the 原因 mentioned earlier in the paragraph.

- narrator suddenly understood the reason for the attention
- the reason is the attractive appearance (容姿) of this inanity-spewing goddess

In your try at the translation ("...said the beautiful goddess who suddenly was saying nonsense"), "goddess" is your subject.

However for the original sentence, 容姿 is the subject, as it explains the attention - it's not just the goddess, but the goddess' attractive looks getting the attention.

It lies at the end of "このすっとぼけた事を言う女神の容姿" as the sentence construct literally translates to "[the reason for the attention is] this inanity-spewing goddess' appearance".

As you can see, it's a very stiff literal translation :) The translation you quoted also did not specify "looks/appearance" explicitly, but worked round it to capture the outcome as naturally as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Much more clear now !